# How to display complex fractions in Objective C: NSString? NSAttributedString?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

Is it possible to display fractions using any of the `NSString`-like classes in Cocoa?

For example I would like to display the fraction (x+2)/(x-4) as an `NSString` where (x+2) is sitting above a line above the expression (x-4). Here's an image of a more complicated example:

[image]

I can already think about how to do so using a bunch of `NSView`s, but was wondering if there's a better way of doing it.

Comment: Couldn't you just build a custom fraction class with a method called "print". Then have that class take care of the printing by generating the NSString, padding, formatting, and all that?

Comment: Don't understand the votes to close this... Pretty clear what the question is to me.

Comment: @schmudu: Please clarify whether this is for OS X or iOS...

Comment: This is for OS X.  Thanks all for the comments.  I think I'm going to try Freddy's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UIWebView` instance and the opensource [MathJax library](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/installation.html) to render your math code written in proper [TeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX).

Comment: The problem with something like this is the fact that UIWebViews can be slow, and have horrid performance when multiple are on-screen.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I've just tested it and it's smooth. Also, why would you need multiple ones?

Comment: The slowness usually happens when lots of a javascript is included. But small web views with one task in mind should not be a problem performance wise.